# How to use Java Stream with empty list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to use Java Stream in this code, but I don't know how it to work with an empty list.

I'm trying to find something like a `while` in Stream Java 8, but I can't find it.

```
public static List<DateBucket> bucketize(ZonedDateTime fromDate, ZonedDateTime toDate, int bucketSize, ChronoUnit bucketSizeUnit) {

    List<DateBucket> buckets = new ArrayList<>();;
    boolean reachedDate = false;

    for (int i = 0; !reachedDate; i++) {
        ZonedDateTime minDate = fromDate.plus(i * bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit);
        ZonedDateTime maxDate = fromDate.plus((i + 1) * bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit);
        reachedDate = toDate.isBefore(maxDate);
        buckets.add(new DateBucket(minDate.toInstant(), maxDate.toInstant()));
    }

    return buckets;
}
```

I expect to avoid the `for` and use Stream in the major portion of code.

Comment: "I need to use Java Stream in this code" No you don't. It's working perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, but is a requirements that I do it with Stream.

Comment: Implementation details are not requirements.

Comment: Tell that to the teacher / lecturer ;-)

Comment: Maybe you want `takeWhile` on streams, which was only introduced in Java 9: https://blog.indrek.io/articles/whats-new-in-java-9-streams/

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Yes, that's the only exception. In such a case they learn nothing from us doing for them.

Comment: @GyroGearless Thank, but I am working with Java 8.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt It is a real requirement, It's not for the University.

Comment: Why does an empty list effect this? The list always starts out as empty in your method

Comment: Yes, but How I populate an empty list with Stream?

Comment: You would use `Collectors.toList()` instead of populating an empty list. But I wouldn't do it with Java 8 Streams - not without Java 9's `takeWhile()` addition.

Comment: Sure, I think same, but I am working with Java 8 and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: But why do you say the using Stream is a _requirement_ if this is not a learning assignment and you have an alternative way to do it?

Comment: Cause the client require it

Comment: @AldoFernandoSaia as mentioned before, in the comments, the stream solution is not the best approach for this problem. Even if it is currently working as expected, it's cumberstone to expand / debug it.  Streams / lamba expressions are best used in functional programming. That style tries to avoid having a state, and that's exactly what you have. Stick to the more simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `LongStream` to start and `mapToObj()` to create your `DateBucket`s:

```
public static List<DateBucket> bucketize(ZonedDateTime fromDate, ZonedDateTime toDate, int bucketSize, ChronoUnit bucketSizeUnit) {
    return LongStream.rangeClosed(0, bucketSizeUnit.between(fromDate, toDate))
            .mapToObj(i -> {
                ZonedDateTime minDate = fromDate.plus(i * bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit);
                ZonedDateTime maxDate = fromDate.plus((i + 1) * bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit);
                return new DateBucket(minDate.toInstant(), maxDate.toInstant());
            })
            .filter(b -> {
                ZonedDateTime maxDate = b.getMaxDate().atZone(toDate.getZone());
                ZonedDateTime limitDate = toDate.plus(bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit);
                return maxDate.isBefore(limitDate) || maxDate.isEqual(limitDate);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This creates an IntStream from `0` to the max possible index between the given dates, maps each index to a `DateBucket` and filters the result for the required range.

If you can use **Java 9** I would recommend using `IntStream.iterate()` instead of `Intstream.rangeClosed()` and `takeWhile()` instead of `filter()`:

```
public static List<DateBucket> bucketize(ZonedDateTime fromDate, ZonedDateTime toDate, int bucketSize, ChronoUnit bucketSizeUnit) {
    return LongStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
            .mapToObj(i -> {
                ZonedDateTime minDate = fromDate.plus(i * bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit);
                ZonedDateTime maxDate = fromDate.plus((i + 1) * bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit);
                return new DateBucket(minDate.toInstant(), maxDate.toInstant());
            })
            .takeWhile(b -> {
                ZonedDateTime maxDate = b.getMaxDate().atZone(toDate.getZone());
                ZonedDateTime limitDate = toDate.plus(bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit);
                return maxDate.isBefore(limitDate) || maxDate.isEqual(limitDate);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But none of this methods will have a better performance than the solution you already have.

Comment: Performance is one thing, second is readability. His for loop is intuitive at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Stream.iterate` to generate a list, you need to provide two args, the first is a initial argument, and the second is a function to process the previous argument and return the next one:

```java
        public static List<DateBucket> bucketize(ZonedDateTime fromDate, ZonedDateTime toDate, int bucketSize, ChronoUnit bucketSizeUnit) {
                List buckets = Stream.iterate(
                                new DateBucket(
                                        fromDate.toInstant(),
                                        fromDate.plus(bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit).toInstant()
                                ),
                                (DateBucket db) -> new DateBucket(db.to, db.to.plus( bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit))
                        )
                        .limit(bucketSizeUnit.between(fromDate, toDate) / bucketSize)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                return buckets;
        }
```